# PostgreSQL - very slow table join on OSM data

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

I have trouble with creating a join of tables. Query runs forever. I have open street map bicycle routes in one table with all the attributes.

```
Table planet_osm_line
osm_id bigint,
route text,
name text,
network text,
osmc_color text,
reversed text,
state text,
"instance:cycle" text,
"relation:id" text,
ref text,
description text,
distance text,
tags hstore,
way geometry(LineString,900913)
```

Some of the lines are duplicated (2 or more routes on one way) so I filtered unique lines into another table and I tried to merge them with data from planet_osm_line:

```
DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS  public.bicycle_merge;
CREATE TABLE public.bicycle_merge AS

WITH singleRow as ( 
   select count(way), way
   from planet_osm_line 
   WHERE route IN ('bicycle')
   group by way
   having count(way) = 1
)
SELECT P.*
FROM planet_osm_line P
JOIN singleRow S
  ON P.way = S.way
;
```

This query runs forever....Forgive my newbie question but what am I doing wrong?

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=28767.43..172920474.87 rows=5892712 width=335)"
"  Join Filter: (p.way = s.way)"
"  CTE singlerow"
"    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=27040.24..28767.43 rows=76764 width=218)"
"          Filter: (count(planet_osm_line1.way) = 1)"
"          ->  Sort  (cost=27040.24..27232.15 rows=76764 width=218)"
"                Sort Key: planet_osm_line1.way"
"                ->  Seq Scan on planet_osm_line1  (cost=0.00..4543.55     rows=76764 width=218)"
```

Planet_osm_line table has around 70.000 rows. Unique geometries are around 50.000.
This query works on a small set of data but now I'm dealing with bicycle routes in the whole country (Poland). Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `group by way having count(way) = 1` essentially does nothing, you could `select distinct way from planet_osm_line`. But that doesn't require a CTE to use, which acts as an optimization barrier, so you could just just use `SELECT DISTINCT ON (way) * FROM planet_osm_line WHERE route = 'bicycle' ORDER BY way`.

Comment: This actually works but it also list the lines which have duplicates. I want to avoid that. I need the lines which exist only ones in the table.

Comment: which defines a duplicate? `distinct on (way)` should remove multiple rows with the same `way` column. Or you want to remove all of the rows, which have duplicates (and not just all except one)?

Comment: sometimes there are 2 ways with exactly the same geometry but with different attributes. I just check and the query left these geometries but probably only the first encountered.

Comment: what does that join actually accomplish? Join is going out of hand with nested loop, something is not right in that query

Comment: I need to find geometries which exists ones, twice etc. After I have them i separate tables I can add specific attributes to them and render them differently on map. For example when you have 2 bicycle routes on one way, one is rendered with 5 px offset, second one is rendered with 10 px offset.

Comment: here is an example http://pomorskieszlaki.pl/#16/54.5119/18.4893/osm-rowerowe-piesze  you can see 2 bicycle routes which have different attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are joining on two plain geometries. This means that you are making a binary comparison of the geometries, byte for byte, between all possible matches. That will take a serious amount of time indeed. In your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` the CTE has a cost of 28,767; the join is a **factor 6,000** larger.

Instead, you should test if two geometries touch each other (since OSM is properly geocoded you can assume that there are no line intersections):

```
WITH singleRow AS ( 
   SELECT count(way), way
   FROM planet_osm_line 
   WHERE route IN ('bicycle')
   GROUP BY way
   HAVING count(way) = 1
)
SELECT P.*
FROM planet_osm_line P
JOIN singleRow S ON ST_Contains(P.way, S.way);
```

On the set of rows you retrieve like this you can then apply the function `ST_MakeLine()` to actually merge the smaller lines into one.

Comment: Great answer. I actually changed ST_Touches to ST_Contains and it works fine. ST_Touches didn't work properly but thank you anyway :)

Comment: My query took 14 seconds. That's very much acceptable. Thanks again!